# Table 'AspNetUsers' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to convert a 10+ year old database to our new format and using EFCore to do the ETL.
And here is the method that is throwing me an error on.

```cs
internal void GetAllUsers(string? userName = null) {
            List<AspNetUser> oldUsers = new List<AspNetUser>();

            if (userName is not null)
            {
                oldUsers = _oldContext.AspNetUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == userName).ToList();
                //if (!oldUsers.Any()) Console.WriteLine("No Users Found Exiting");
                //return;
            }
            if (userName is null) oldUsers.AddRange(_oldContext.AspNetUsers.OrderBy(x => x.Id));
            foreach (var user in oldUsers) {
                var newUser = ConvertAspNetUserToConnexUser(user);
                Console.WriteLine($"Converting user: {0}", newUser.UserName);
                CreateUserConnections(ref newUser);
                CreateLicenseKey(newUser);
                CreateTaxCodes(newUser);
                if (_newContext.ConnexUsers.Any(x => x.Id == newUser.Id))
                    newUser.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _newContext.ConnexUsers.Add(newUser);
                AnsiConsole.WriteLine($"Inserting user: {0} to the new database.", newUser.UserName);
                try {
                    _newContext.Database.OpenConnection();
                    _newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [AspNetUsers] ON");
                    _newContext.SaveChanges();
                    _newContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [AspNetUsers] OFF");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    AnsiConsole.WriteLine($"Problem Inserting {user. Email}");
                    throw new Exception($"Problem inserting the user {newUser.Email}: ", ex);
                } finally {
                    _newContext.Database.CloseConnection();
                }
            }
            
        }
```

This is the user object that I have for our users.

```
public class CustomUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RuleSet> RuleSets { get; set; } = new List<RuleSet>();
    public ICollection<UserCompany> UserCompanies { get; set; } = new List<UserCompany>();
    public bool IsQuickBooksSandBox { get; set; }
    public string? ConnectionName { get; set; }

}
```

If I don't set IDENITITY_INSERT OFF then I will get another error as well

***SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserConnections' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.***

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDENTITY property has to be declared on table creation. Make sure your [AspNetUsers] table actually has an identity. If you are recreating a database from scratch then injecting the old values you could do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUsers] (
[Id]                                        INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName ]                                NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[LastName]                              NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
[LastModificationDate]                      DATETIME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SinisterProvisionThresholdDb] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),);
```

Otherwise if you already have your columns populated or don't want to drop your table, check out [this link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/) with a workaround.